# create a list by mapping values between lists

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree

I have following 2 lists: `X_train` and `y_train`. I want to return four lists. The first containing the rows from `X_train` which have `outlook == overcast`, the second containing the labels for those rows. The third and fourth lists should contain the same but then for the rows which have a different outlook.

```
X_train = [['sunny', 'hot', 'high', 'FALSE'],
 ['sunny', 'hot', 'high', 'TRUE'],
 ['overcast', 'hot', 'high', 'FALSE'],
 ['rainy', 'mild', 'high', 'FALSE'],
 ['rainy', 'cool', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
 ['rainy', 'cool', 'normal', 'TRUE'],
 ['overcast', 'cool', 'normal', 'TRUE'],
 ['sunny', 'mild', 'high', 'FALSE'],
 ['sunny', 'cool', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
 ['rainy', 'mild', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
 ['sunny', 'mild', 'normal', 'TRUE'],
 ['overcast', 'mild', 'high', 'TRUE'],
 ['overcast', 'hot', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
 ['rainy', 'mild', 'high', 'TRUE']]

y_train = ['no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no']
```

My code is as follows:

```
overcast=[]
for row in X_train:
    if 'overcast' in row:
        overcast+=[row]
```

The output of `overcast` list is:

```
[['overcast', 'hot', 'high', 'FALSE'],
 ['overcast', 'cool', 'normal', 'TRUE'],
 ['overcast', 'mild', 'high', 'TRUE'],
 ['overcast', 'hot', 'normal', 'FALSE']]
```

My expected output is:

```
([['sunny', 'hot', 'high', 'FALSE'],
  ['sunny', 'hot', 'high', 'TRUE'],
  ['rainy', 'mild', 'high', 'FALSE'],
  ['rainy', 'cool', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
  ['rainy', 'cool', 'normal', 'TRUE'],
  ['sunny', 'mild', 'high', 'FALSE'],
  ['sunny', 'cool', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
  ['rainy', 'mild', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
  ['sunny', 'mild', 'normal', 'TRUE'],
  ['rainy', 'mild', 'high', 'TRUE']],
 ['no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no'],
 [['overcast', 'hot', 'high', 'FALSE'],
  ['overcast', 'cool', 'normal', 'TRUE'],
  ['overcast', 'mild', 'high', 'TRUE'],
  ['overcast', 'hot', 'normal', 'FALSE']],
 ['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes'])
```

Now I am stuck at how to append the labels '`yes`' and '`no`' corresponding to the '`overcast`' set, which should be four '`yes`'.
ANy ideas to help me out please, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to filter or transform tabular data like these, [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) can be very convenient, for example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(X_train, columns=['outlook', 'temperature', 'pressure', 'Boole'])
df['y'] = y_train

df[df.outlook == 'overcast']
```

```
    outlook     temperature     pressure    Boole   y
2   overcast    hot             high        FALSE   yes
6   overcast    cool            normal      TRUE    yes
11  overcast    mild            high        TRUE    yes
12  overcast    hot             normal      FALSE   yes
```

If you must return lists, you can cast the dataframe to a nested list like this:

```py
df[df.outlook == 'overcast'].drop('y', axis=1).values.tolist()
```

```
[['overcast', 'hot', 'high', 'FALSE'],
 ['overcast', 'cool', 'normal', 'TRUE'],
 ['overcast', 'mild', 'high', 'TRUE'],
 ['overcast', 'hot', 'normal', 'FALSE']]
```

Or for the labels:

```py
df.y[df.outlook == 'overcast'].values.tolist()
```

```
['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes']
```

Comment: it is possible solution. Thanks, but I want to return 4 lists

Comment: I added a way to get lists at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

For a more basic approach, you could use list comprehensions, e.g. like this:

```py
# extract the first column from X_train
outlook = [row[0] for row in X_train]

# create a Boolean list  
outlook_is_overcast = [x == 'overcast' for x in outlook]

# get the y values for which x is overcast
[y_train[i] for i in range(len(y_train)) if outlook_is_overcast[i]]
```

```
['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes']
```